# How can I suppress the output of a command in octave?

Tags: command-line, octave

In Octave I can suppress or hide the output of an instruction adding a semicolon to the end of a line:

```
octave:1> exp([0 1])
ans = [ 1.0000   2.7183 ]
octave:2> exp([0 1]);
octave:3>
```

Now, how can I suppress the output if the function displays text (e.g. using `disp()` or `print()`) before returning its value? In other words, I want to be able to do this:

```
disp("Starting...");
% hide text the may get displayed after this point
% ...
% show all text again after this point
disp("Done!");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can modify the `PAGER` variable (which is now a function) to redirect standard output. On Unix systems, you can redirect it to `/dev/null`. On Windows, I tried simply redirecting to a Python program that does nothing, and it works decently. (Basically, any program that ignores the input will do)

```
PAGER('/dev/null');
page_screen_output(1);
page_output_immediately(1);
```

You can just change it back after you're done. And maybe encapsulate this whole procedure in a function.

```
oldpager = PAGER('/dev/null');
oldpso = page_screen_output(1);
oldpoi = page_output_immediately(1);

% Call function here

PAGER(oldpager);
page_screen_output(oldpso);
page_output_immediately(oldpoi);
```

You can also simply run your scripts non-interactively, and redirect the output normally.

```
octave script.m > /dev/null
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage of disabling all text display, and I would like to be able to hide text from a single method but still being able to display my own text.

Comment: Just change it back after you call the function. I gave an example. There's no other real convenient way of accomplishing this, that I know of.

Answer (score 3):

A quick hack of your problem and maybe not even worth mentioning is overloading the `disp` function like so:

```
function disp(x)
end
```

Then the original `disp` function is not called but yours instead in which no output is generated.

I also tried to somehow redirect `stdout` of octave, but unsuccessful. I hope that this dirty solution maybe will suffice in your situation^^

Comment: This has the problem of making the `disp` function completely unavailable, even for my own use. Plus, a given function may make use of other methods to display text (e.g. print, sprintf, printf, etc)

Comment: @andersonvom I agree. It is as I mentioned a quick hack. Though you could still make use of the `disp` method if you use a second parameter like `function disp(x, y) if nargin > 1 printf("%d", y)`. Still it remains a hack, and I am still interested in *nice* answer^^.

Comment: overloading disp does not stop output from printf or omitting ;

Answer (score 3):

It's a very old question, but still, I've encountered the same problem and here is the trick that can help. One can use `evalc` to wrap a problematic function call. E.g. you have a code:

```
[a, b] = verbose_func(x,y);
```

Now you can do it:

```
evalc('[a, b] = verbose_func(x,y)');
```

and make it silent.

Funny, but it even works with other `eval` inside. I mean we can have:

```
code_str = '[a, b] = verbose_func(x,y)';
eval(code_str);
```

which is verbose. Now:

```
code_str = '[a, b] = verbose_func(x,y)';
evalc('eval(code_str)');
```

and this is not.