# 'sh: /dev/null: Permission denied' when using PAGER('/dev/null') on OS X

Tags: macos, octave

I'm trying to suppress some of the output from octave as per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8303754/1033422:

```
oldpager = PAGER('/dev/null');
oldpso = page_screen_output(1);
oldpoi = page_output_immediately(1);

... do some stuff

PAGER(oldpager);
page_screen_output(oldpso);
page_output_immediately(oldpoi);
```

However, when I run my script, octave is displaying the error:

```
sh: /dev/null: Permission denied
```

---

**Update:**

```
$ ls -l /dev/null
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    3,   2 24 Jan 19:07 /dev/null
```

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/null` show?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`PAGER`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Paging-Screen-Output.html#XREFPAGER) is expecting a *program* (such as `less`) and `/dev/null` is not a program.

> Query or set the internal variable that specifies the program to use to display terminal output on your system.

Instead, what you could do would be to set `PAGER` such that it uses `less` but then pipes the output directly to `/dev/null`

```
PAGER('less > /dev/null')
```